# Lucene : Changing the default facet delimiter?

Tags: java, groovy, lucene, facet

First post on this wonderful site!

My goal is to use hierarchical facets for searching an index using Lucene.  However, my facets need to be delimited by a character other than '/', (in this case, '~'). Example:

Categories
Categories~Category1
Categories~Category2

I have created a class that implements FacetIndexingParams interface (a copy of DefaultFacetIndexingParams with the DEFAULT_FACET_DELIM_CHAR param set to '~').

Paraphrased indexing code : (using FSDirectory for both index and taxonomy)

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34)
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_34, analyzer)
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, config)
TaxonomyWriter taxo = new LuceneTaxonomyWriter(taxDir, OpenMode.CREATE)

Document doc = new Document()
// Add bunch of Fields... hidden for the sake of brevity
List<CategoryPath> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryPath>()
row.tags.split('\\|').each{ tag ->
    def cp = new CategoryPath()
    tag.split('~').each{
        cp.add(it)
    }
    categories.add(cp)
}
NewFacetIndexingParams facetIndexingParams = new NewFacetIndexingParams()
DocumentBuilder categoryDocBuilder = new CategoryDocumentBuilder(taxo, facetIndexingParams)
categoryDocBuilder.setCategoryPaths(categories).build(doc)
writer.addDocument(doc)

// Commit and close both writer and taxo.
```

Search code paraphrased:

```
// Create index and taxonomoy readers to get info from index and taxonomy
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(indexDir)
TaxonomyReader taxo = new LuceneTaxonomyReader(taxDir)
Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader)

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34, "content", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34))
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)
Query q = parser.parse(query)
TopScoreDocCollector tdc = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true)
List<FacetResult> res = null
NewFacetIndexingParams facetIndexingParams = new NewFacetIndexingParams()
FacetSearchParams facetSearchParams = new FacetSearchParams(facetIndexingParams)
CountFacetRequest cfr = new CountFacetRequest(new CategoryPath(""), 99)
cfr.setDepth(2)
cfr.setSortBy(SortBy.VALUE)
facetSearchParams.addFacetRequest(cfr)
FacetsCollector facetsCollector = new FacetsCollector(facetSearchParams, indexReader, taxo)

def cp = new CategoryPath("Category~Category1", (char)'~')
searcher.search(DrillDown.query(q, cp), MultiCollector.wrap(tdc, facetsCollector))
```

The results always return a list of facets in the form of "Category/Category1".

I have used the Luke tool to look at the index and it appears the facets are being delimited by the '~' character in the index.

What is the best route to do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out the issue.  The search and indexing are working as they are supposed to.  It is how I have been getting the facet results that is the issue.  I was using :

```
res = facetsCollector.getFacetResults()
res.each{ result ->
    result.getFacetResultNode().getLabel().toString()
}
```

What I needed to use was :

```
res = facetsCollector.getFacetResults()
res.each{ result ->
    result.getFacetResultNode().getLabel().toString((char)'~')
}
```

The difference being the paramter sent to the toString function!

Easy to overlook, tough to find.

Hope this helps others.